# Finite morphism induced by section of a line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Assume $X$ is smooth, irreducible curve (curve = $1$-dimensional proper scheme over a fixed base field $k$)  and $x \in X$ a closed point. Since $\{x\}$ is a divisor of $X$, we obtain a line bundle $\mathcal{L}:= O_X(\{x\})$ a.k.a. invertible sheaf on $X$. We assume that  $\dim_k H^0(\mathcal{L}, X) \ge 2$. Therefore $H^0(\mathcal{L}, X)$ contains a non constant section $f \in H^0(\mathcal{L}, X)$. $f$ we can also see as an element of fraction field $K(X)$ of $X$ and therefore we can talk about $(f),(1/f)$ as $O_X$-modules.

Let $U_f:=X \backslash \text{Supp}(f)$ and $U_{1/f}:=X \backslash \text{Supp}(1/f)$. We obtain a cover $X=U_f \cup U_{1/f}$ of $X$ and can define a well defined map $f: X \to \mathbb{P}^1 _k= \text{Proj}(k[T_0,T_1])$ as follows on affine pieces:

$U_f \to D_+(T_0)$ corresponds to $T_1/T_0 \mapsto f$ and $U_{1/f} \to D_+(T_1)$ corresponds to $T_0/T_1 \mapsto 1/f$. It's easy exercise to verify that these maps glue to a map $f: X \to \mathbb{P}^1 _k$. By construction $f$ is affine and $f^{-1}(\infty)=x$, because $f$ is non constant and $\mathcal{L}= O_X(\{x\})$ (recall,  $\infty =(0:1) \in \mathbb{P}^1$).

My question is why is $f$ a finite morphism? Since it's a local property and $f$ is defined on affine pieces symmetrically, that suffice to understand why is $k[T_1/T_0] \to O_X(U_f),  T_1/T_0 \mapsto f$ is a finite map or equivalently why is  $O_X(U_f)$ a finite $k[T_1/T_0]$-module?

Comment: I'd say there is finite type ($O_X(U)$ is finitely generated $k$-algebra) in the definition of  proper $k$-scheme, irreducible means $O_X(U)$ is an integral domain (since otherwise looking at its minimal prime ideals would give reducibility), so $Frac(O_X(U))$ is a finite extension of $k(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$, 1-dimensional means $n=1$ so $Frac(O_X(U))$ is a finite extension of $k(f)$ for any $f$ non-constant (non-algebraic over $k$)

Comment: yes, this looks nice. we consider the finite injection of fields $k(T_1/t_0) \to Frac(O_X(U))$. thus we can identify $k(T_1/T_0)$ with it's image $k(f)$ and $Frac(O_X(U))$ is finite over $k(f)$. the last problem is to conclude that this implies $O_X(U)$ is finite over $k[f] \cong k[T_1/T_0]$. or generally is that true that if $\phi: R \to A$ is a injective ring morphism and the induced map $\bar{\phi}:Frac(R) \to Frac(A)$ is finite, then $\phi$ is finite?

Comment: @katalaveino I think the more general statement does not hold: $\varphi: \mathbb Z\rightarrow \mathbb Q$ is not finite, but it induces a finite map $\mathbb Q\rightarrow \mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was intended as a comment, but it is too long to fit in.

I think in this case $\mathcal L$ is an ample line bundle of $X$, and the morphism $f$ in question is the canonical morphism ([stacks project Lemma 01PZ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01PZ)).

Since the canonical morphism is an open immersion ([stacks project Lemma 01Q1](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01Q1)), the morphism $k[T_1/T_0]\rightarrow\mathcal O_X(U_f)$ should be a localization. Since being finite is a local property ([stacks project Lemma 01WI](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01WI)), we may assume it is the localization at one element.

Since $X$ is a curve over $k$, that element should be finite over $k$ (as it is proper over $k$), i.e. satisfy a polynomial equation with coefficients in $k$. This shows that the localization in question is finite.

---

Perhaps there is a simpler way to show this, but I hope this could still be of some use.

---

Please point it out if some errors occur or if there are any inappropriate points, thanks.

**EDIT:**

$(1):$

Consider a ring extension $A\subseteq B$ and $x\in B$ which is finite over $A$. Then $A_x$ is finite over $A$. This is because $x$ being finite over $A$ implies $x$ is integral over $A$, and hence $x$ satisfies a monic equation $x^n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_ix^i=0$. Dividing by $x^n$, we have
$$1+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_ix^{i-n}=0.$$
As a consequence $A_x/A$ is generated by $\{1/x^k\mid k = 0, \cdots, n-1\}$ as a module.

As to why $x$ is finite, see this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125740/why-is-a-proper-affine-morphism-finite), or this [blog post](https://lovelylittlelemmas.rjprojects.net/proper-affine-finite/).

$(2):$

Not any localization is the localization at one element: For example, consider the localization $\mathbb Z_{(2)}$ of $\mathbb Z$ at the prime ideal $(2)$: it consists of elements of the form $\frac ab$, where $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ and $2\not\mid b$. There is no element $x$ such that $\mathbb Z_{(2)}=\mathbb Z_x$ (otherwise $x$ has infinitely many prime divisors).

On the other hand, I think my original argument involving PID is wrong, so I edited the above argument as well. Thanks for pointing out the flaw.

Comment: why the fact, that the single element $s$, which gives the localisation $k[T_1/T_0]\rightarrow\mathcal O_X(U_f)=k[T_1/T_0]_s$, is proper (over $k$), implies that it is also finite?

Comment: a second remark: you say "ince the canonical morphism is an open immersion , the morphism $k[T_1/T_0]\rightarrow\mathcal O_X(U_f)$ should be a localization (at one element, since $k[T_1/T_0]$ is a P.I.D.). I don't understand the interplay with P.I.D. property. isn't that true that every ring map $A \to B$, that is a localization, can be realized by localisation at a single element? i.e. $B \cong A_s$ with $s \in A$. in other words: is the PID condition neccessary?

Comment: I made an edit, trying to explain the questions. If it is not clear or if you have more questions, feel free to ask. :)

Comment: do you maybe know if the claim could also be proved as a 'corollar' from Noether normalisation theorem? namely NNT tells me in our case that if $A$ is integral $k$-algebra of dimension $1$, then there exist a finite injection $K[X] \to A$. can from NNT instantly derived that if we take arbitrary non constant $f \in A$, i.e. $f \not \in k$, then after replacing $X$ by $f$, $A$ stays finite over $k[f]$. your proof above is indeed fine, but looking through the statement of NNT it looks so alluring that the claim of my post can also be easily dereved from that.

Comment: Indeed NNT tells us that there is a finite injection $K[x]\hookrightarrow A$. But I do not know how to show that the image of $x$ can be chosen to be any $f\not\in K$.